# How to delete a span and play a youtube video under the span on click?

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have a small gallery of youtube videos that don't play on load. On hovering over them, a span appears with a description. I'd like the span to disappear upon clicking on it and the video to start. Seems I can get the span to disappear, but the video won't start...

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="vid-list">
<li>
<a class="img-link" href="#" onclick="{document.getElementById('vid1_span').remove(); document.getElementById("vid1_frame").src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1";}">
<iframe id="vid1_frame" width="90%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
<span id="vid1_span" class="text-content"><span>Woohoo!</span></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

and here is the CSS to go with it:

```
a.img-link:link
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#556270;
font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:1.2em;
}

a.img-link:hover
{
background-color:none;
}

ul.vid-list {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
width:100%;
}

ul.vid-list li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding-top:0.7em;
position: relative;
width: 23%;
height:11em;
}

span.text-content {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
display: table;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height:11em;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms;
transition: opacity 500ms;
}

ul.vid-list li:hover span.text-content {
opacity: 1;
}

span.text-content span {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If I remove the second command in the "onclick", the span is deleted on click. If I leave it there, it won't delete the span, nor start the video.

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because your `onclick` has invalid quotes:

```
<ul class="vid-list">
<li>
<a class="img-link" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('vid1_span').remove(); document.getElementById('vid1_frame').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1';">
<iframe id="vid1_frame" width="90%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=0" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen> </iframe>
<span id="vid1_span" class="text-content"><span>Woohoo!</span></span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Haven't noticed those... now there's a problem with the "a" class, but I'll fix that.

Comment: @NikolaPoljak Problem? I can help.

Comment: @NikolaPoljak If my answer helped, please upvote and/or accept! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".img-link").click(function () {
            $("#vid1_span").remove();
            $("#vid1_frame").attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1")
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
  <ul class="vid-list">
    <li>
        <a class="img-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <iframe id="vid1_frame" width="90%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
            <span id="vid1_span" class="text-content"><span>Woohoo!</span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```